# Django changes data to tuple on save

Tags: python, django

When a customer registers on my website, I check if the user's email is already registered with the website or not. If the user is already registered then I simply update the old data with the new data which is entered by the user. But in the case of an update, Django changes the data to the tuple.

Below is my code

Models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
```

**Views.py**

If email is there

```
user_data = get_object_or_404(Customer, email = email)
user_data.first_name = 'Test'
user_data.save()
```

But it changes the data in the database to the tuple. Like below

**Django Admin**

[image]

When the customer registers for the first time, data is saved correctly. But when a user registers again there's a problem

I'm using Python 3.5 and Django 2.2

Comment: please always post the exact error message or show the result, that you received and the result that you expected.

Comment: @gelonida I've uploaded the screenshot. Please check.

Comment: you can use "Customer.objects.update_or_create()". This create new data if email is not registered otherwise it will update the existing data.

Comment: why are you using CharField for email?

Comment: @sandeep Thank you! It worked

Comment: The code you're showing cannot produce this, please show the exact code. Assigning the string "Test" to `user_data.first_name` will correctly save "Test" as the first name. You say the user changes it, so you should show the code for how that happens.

Comment: @dirkgroten Thanks for the comment. But now it's resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem as I was trying to do this process manually. But as I didn't find any material about it, I found a video explaining that the best way is to use custom forms

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5iR-oKjNEg0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).